# Qual é o limite de uso do .push_back()?

Tags: c++, desempenho, vector

Costumo usar muito `.push_back(element)` quando estou trabalhando com `vector`, porém não sei qual é o máximo de elementos que consigo adicionar a um `vector` antes que ele transborde e execute a realocação de um novo espaço na memoria.

Existe algum mecanismo que posso usar para saber o máximo de elementos que o `vector` suporta? Esse valor é sempre o mesmo, de forma que se compilar para qualquer máquina esse valor não irá mudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é dependente de implementação e pode variar de acordo com a arquitetura, compilador, versão e até de fatores extras conforme o uso, então não pode trabalhar com um número.

Eu acredito que a maioria das implementações irão dobrar o espaço alocado a cada relocação.

Você pode [dar um valor inicial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) ou [fazer a mudança de tamanho manualmente antes que ele faça automático](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01115_source.html

Comment: Mais atual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/libstdc++/api/a15915_source.html

Answer (score 2):

> Existe algum mecanismo que posso usar para saber o máximo de elementos que o vector suporta?

Sim,

- [`std::vector::capacity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) retorna o número de elementos para quais o contêiner atualmente alocou espaço, e
- [`std::vector::max_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size) retorna o número máximo de elementos que o contêiner é capaz de guardar por conta de limitações do sistema ou da implementação da biblioteca.

> Esse valor é sempre o mesmo, de forma que se compilar para qualquer máquina esse valor não irá mudar?

Não, esses valores podem mudar de acordo com o sistema e a implementação.